# Solr equivalent to ElasticSearch Mapping Type

Tags: solr, elasticsearch

ElasticSearch has Mapping Types to, according to the docs:

> Mapping types are a way to divide the documents in an index into
>   logical groups. Think of it as tables in a database.

Is there an equivalent in Solr for this?

I have seen that some people include a new field in the documents and later on they use this new field to limit the search to a certain type of documents, but as I understand it, they have to share the schema and (I believe) ElasticSearch Mapping Type doesn't. So, is there an equivalent?

Or, maybe a better question,

If I have a multiple document types and I want to limit searches to a certain document type, which one should offer a better solution?

I hope this question has any sense since I'm new to both of them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can configure multicore solr:

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CoreAdmin

Maybe something has changed since solr 4.0 and it's easier now, i didn't look at it since i have switched to elasticsearch. Personally i find elasticsearch indexes/types system much  better than that.

Answer (score 0):

In Solr 4+.

If you are planning to do [faceting](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrFacetingOverview) or any other calculations across multiple types than create a single schema with a differentiator field. Then, on your business/mapping/client layer just define only the fields you actually want to look at. Use custom [search handlers](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SearchHandler) with ['fl' field](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters#fl) to only return the fields relevant to that object. Of course, that means that all those single-type-only fields cannot be compulsory.

If your document types are completely disjoint, you can create a core/collection per type, each with its own definition file. You have full separation, but still have only one Solr server to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

> I have seen that some people include a new field in the documents and later on they use this new field to limit the search to a certain type of documents, but as I understand it, they have to share the schema and (I believe) ElasticSearch Mapping Type doesn't.

You can exactly do this in Solr. Add a field and use it to filter.

It is correct that Mapping Types in ElasticSearch do not have to share the same schema but under the hood ElasticSearch uses only ONE schema for all Mapping Types. So technical it makes to difference. In fact the MappingType is mapped to an internal schema field.